# How do you hide join/leave messages in Mibbit?

Tags: irc

Is there a command to hide those messages? I've been searching all over and can't figure it out.

http://www.mibbit.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can change the setting under preferences, under what to show.

[image]

It seems like this is only possible if you have an account.